# How to reduce the use of conditions in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a block of codes in React.js which I believe is not the best way to do it. However, I am not sure how I can simplify and optimize it. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
let date = "";
let locationId = 0,
  movieId = 0;

const urlDate = url.searchParams.get("date");
if (urlDate) {
  if (dateSelectors.filter((x) => x.code === urlDate).length > 0)
    date = urlDate;
  else toast.error("Date retrieved from the URL is invalid");
}
const urlMovie = url.searchParams.get("movieId");
if (urlMovie && urlMovie !== "0") {
  if (
    !Number.isNaN(+urlMovie) &&
    movieSelectors.filter((x) => x.code === urlMovie).length > 0
  )
    movieId = urlMovie;
  else toast.error("Movie Id retrieved from the URL is invalid");
}
const urlLocation = url.searchParams.get("locationId");
if (urlLocation && urlLocation !== "0") {
  if (
    !Number.isNaN(+urlLocation) &&
    locationSelectors.filter((x) => x.code === urlLocation).length > 0
  )
    locationId = urlLocation;
  else toast.error("Theatre Id retrieved from the URL is invalid");
}
```

Comment: Well, the logic of the last two blocks are almost the same, you could make a function to reduce the amount of code and make it easier to read.

Comment: I suggest you look into React Router. It does what you're trying to do here and much more. Definitely worth learning it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very subjective and wide question but here is my suggestion.

Because the last two blocks of code have identical logic, you could make a function to simplify it, like this:

```
const handleUrls = (url, selector) => {
  if (url && url !== "0") {
    if (
      !Number.isNaN(+url) &&
      selector.filter((x) => x.code === url).length > 0
    )
      locationId = urlLocation;
    else toast.error(`The ${url} URL is invalid`);
  }
};

handleUrls(urlLocation, locationSelectors);
handleUrls(urlMovie, movieSelectors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const getValue = (key)=> url.searchParams.get(`${key}`)
const toastOnError = (message)=> toast.error(`${message}`)
let date = "";
let locationId = 0, movieId = 0;

const urlDate = getValue("date");
if (urlDate) {
    date = (dateSelectors.filter(x => x.code === urlDate).length > 0) ? urlDate : "";
    !date && toastOnError("Date retrieved from the URL is invalid")
}
const urlMovie = getValue("movieId");
if (urlMovie && urlMovie !== "0") {
    movieId = (!Number.isNaN(+urlMovie) && movieSelectors.filter(x => x.code === urlMovie).length > 0) ? urlMovie : movieId;
    !movieId && toastOnError("Movie Id retrieved from the URL is invalid");
}
const urlLocation = getValue("locationId");
if (urlLocation && urlLocation !== "0") {
     locationId  = (!Number.isNaN(+urlLocation) && locationSelectors.filter(x => x.code === urlLocation).length > 0) ? urlLocation: locationId;
     !locationId && toastOnError("Theatre Id retrieved from the URL is invalid");
}
```

We can create some handy inline functions to avoid duplication and some formating on conditions. Further, I don't know exactly what do dateSelectors, movieSelectors etc functions do. By optimizing those, you can create a good version of your code.